# Yii2 xml file response

Tags: php, yii2, response, multipartform-data

I have xml file and I want to send it in my api action by http-response with **Content-Type=multipart/form-data**

Now I'm using **Content-Type=text/xml** and my action looks like

```
\Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_RAW;
$headers = \Yii::$app->response->headers;
$headers->add('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
$xml = file_get_contents($filePath);

return $xml;
```

But it is not exactly what I want. How can I change this response to **Content-Type=multipart/form-data**?

Comment: Why would you return multipart form data as response? That should be the input method? `text/html`, `text/xml` or `application/json`

Comment: This is a technical requirement of my api action. Text/xml looks more natural, sure

Comment: Did the answer answer your question?

Comment: see the answer i posted you should not use `echo` in the controller, yii disallowed it since `2.0.14` and should be avoided

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `Content-Type` for the response by customizing the [`XmlResponseFormatter`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-xmlresponseformatter) components property `contentType` to use custom value and then setting the custom formatter on runtime rather than using `echo` manually as since `2.0.14` Yii does not allow echoing in the controller, hence should not be followed. Also using this method will set the `charset` too for the `content-type` headers automatically.

You should do the following to follow a conventional approach

```
public function actionResponder()
{
    $filePath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/assets/test.xml';

    $xml = new XmlResponseFormatter();
    $xml->contentType = 'multipart/form-data';
    Yii::$app->response->format='xml';
    Yii::$app->response->formatters['xml']=$xml;

    $xmlFile = file_get_contents($filePath);

    return $xmlFile;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send response with custom content type in this way:

```
Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_RAW;
Yii::$app->response->headers->add('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
Yii::$app->response->content = file_get_contents($filePath);
return Yii::$app->response;
```